# Change structure of Xml to be imported into Access database

Tags: c#, css, xml, database, xslt

I need to change an XML file that is attribute centric so that it is suitable for importing into an Access database into the columns that are defined.

I have been reading up about XSLT to change the code but have had no luck, the output still doesn't give me the tables in the way I want.

Here's the XML code:

```
<Database>
<ChildRecords>
     <ChildRecord>
         <TableName>Client</TableName>
                  <Columns>
                     <Column Name="id" Data="1234"/>
                     <Column Name="forename" Data="John"/>
                     <Column Name="surname" Data="Smith"/>
                  </Columns>
       </Childrecord>
       <ChildRecord>
         <TableName>Product</TableName>
                  <Columns>
                     <Column Name="id" Data="4321"/>
                     <Column Name="description" Data="Bed"/>
                     <Column Name="price" Data="100"/>
                  </Columns>
       </Childrecord>
</ChildRecords>
</Database>
```

EDIT* Required output code:

```
<Database>
    <Client>
       <id>1234</id>
       <forename>John</forename>
       <surname>Smith</surname>
    </Client>
    <Product>
       <id>1234</id>
       <description>Bed</description>
       <price>100</price>
    </Product>
</Database>
```

Comment: What is the required output code?

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem here? It seems like a fairly trivial transformation. Why don't you post your effort, so we can see where you've gone astray.

Comment: Made an edit to show the output code, sorry I forgot to put it !

Comment: It probably is a trivial issue, this is the first time I've dealt with XML so I've just been following guides online. The examples shown have not gotten me that output, it puts all of the columns into its own table/

Comment: Could you please edit your input and output and show more than one record in the same table? It's rather ambiguous the way you have it now. You should also state if the table names can be hard-coded into the stylesheet.

Comment: MS Access imports any XML, but ignores attributes (see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-xml-and-access-HA001034560.aspx), so moving the attribute data into elements in any format would already allow that. The child elements become table names; grandchildren elements are field names.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following stylesheet. It produces the required output from your input example (once corrected for well-formedness!). I am not sure if the output format is correct for tables with multiple records.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Database>
         <xsl:for-each select="Database/ChildRecords/ChildRecord">
            <xsl:element name="{TableName}">
                <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                    <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Data" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </Database>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```